# How feature is selected to be a decision node after splitting the first root node using entropy in decisions trees?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, entropy, information-gain

In [this article](https://medium.com/@rishabhjain_22692/decision-trees-it-begins-here-93ff54ef134) on how entropy is calculated and how the decision tree is built, the writer chose to split the `sunny` branch into `windy`:

[image]

Instead of taking `humidity` or `temp`.

Based on my calculation, the information gain of `humidity` is **IG(humidity) = 0.152 > IG(windy)=0.048**

In this particular step, where we calculated the entropies and IGs of each branch of outlook (sunny, overcast and rainy), how did he chose to put `windy` under `sunny` and later on `humidity` under `rainy`?